# Visual Studio 2010 Designer File Not Updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, web, designer

**Please, please do not tell me to delete the designer file and convert the page to application - I have done this and it hasn't worked**

I have a user control that I have programmatically added 2 ASP hyperlink controls. I cannot get the controls to appear in the designer file.

I've tried manually adding them to the designer file, but they are removed on build.

I've searched SO and seen the solution about deleting the designer file and converting the ASCX page to an application, this has not worked.

As such, on build, the project errors as it the code cannot find my controls.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hplSiteLink2" NavigateUrl='<%# GetSiteLink(Eval("SiteName"))%>' runat="server">VIEW SITE INFO</asp:HyperLink>

        protected void GetSiteLink(object SiteName) 
    {
        string sn = string.Empty;

        if (SiteName is string)
        {
            sn = SiteName.ToString();

            if (sn == "redlionnewquay")
            {
                hplSiteLink.NavigateUrl = "http://www.redlionnewquay.co.uk";
                hplSiteLink2.NavigateUrl = "http://www.redlionnewquay.co.uk";
            }
            else
            {
                hplSiteLink.NavigateUrl = "~/Venue/Home/" + Eval("SiteNameUrl");
                hplSiteLink2.NavigateUrl = "~/Venue/Home/" + Eval("SiteNameUrl");
            }   
        }          
    }
```

If you have any ideas I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if you remove & re-add a control, and the designer doesn't get updated, it may be due to a permissions problem - are you sure that all the files are writable, and that you have permissions?

Do you have any other user controls that work properly?  I've seen cases where the extension (ascx) for some reason loses it's associations, so VS doesn't know how to handle it properly.  If you switch views, does that make any difference?  Any chance of a name collision in the project?

Finally, if nothing else works, try deleting the user control from the project, closing Visual Studio, then re-open the solution & try adding a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Right, I think I've solved it. I was set on the right track by other topics on this subject stating if there are any errors in your code it will not generate the designer file.

With this in mind I looked over and over the procedure and realised I was running the Eval in the if statement - which is rubbish, so I changed the code to this:

```
        public string GetSiteLink(object SiteName)
    {
        string sn = string.Empty;
        string sHtml = string.Empty;

        if (SiteName is string)
        {
            sn = SiteName.ToString();

            if (sn == "redlionnewquay")
            {
                sHtml = "http://www.redlionnewquay.co.uk";
            }
            else
            {
                sHtml = "~/Venue/Home/" + SiteName;
            }
        }
        return sHtml;
    }
```

Which solved it, although it was not obvious as the previous code compiled without error, the Eval in code behind I guess is a 'soft' error.

Thanks for your help.